# Closing Perspective Broker connection in Twisted

Tags: python, twisted, rpc

I have program which has servers interacting with each other using Twisted's remote procedure calls, and I run in problems with closing connections when they are not needed anymore. Connections should be able to close itself in both sides.

Case 1: How do I close connection in connecting part?

```
factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
reactor.connectTCP(ip, port, factory)
deferred = factory.login(credentials.UsernamePassword(username, password), client=self)
deferred.addCallbacks(self.connectedToServer, self.errorConnectingToServer)

def connectedToServer(self, server):
  self.server = server
  # Closing connection comes here
```

Case 2: How do I close connection in server part?

```
class MyPerspective(pb.Avatar):

  def connected(self, server):
    self.client = server
    # Closing connection comes here
```

At the moment I use raising pb.Error() to close connection, but I don't think that's the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is `reference.broker.transport.loseConnection()`.

`RemoteReference` instances which are created over a PB connection are given a `broker` attribute.  The `broker` attribute refers to the protocol instance that created them.  As usual for a protocol, the broker has a `transport` attribute, and the transport has a `loseConnection` method.